# Rails3 Sprockets JS concatenation: Best practice to avoid JS conflicts

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sprockets

Lets say there are two pages with two different html elements which have the same name

```
a.html
<select id='collection_select'></select>


b.html
<select id='collection_select'></select>
```

and there is a javascript function which is only to be applied to `a.html`

```
a.js
$(function(){
  $('#collection_select').change(function(){
    ....
  })
})
```

Becase Rails concatenates all JS assets, this function will now also apply to `b.html`. Is there a Rails/Sprockets/JS best practice to structure and namespace JS assets in a particular way so that the scope of the JS is limited to a particular page.

Comment: I think this is a good question (I asked a similar one recently) but I can't help but saying the best practice is give better ids to your selects. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blog post presents a good way of going this: http://viget.com/inspire/extending-paul-irishs-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution

To summarize it involves

1. Putting a `data-controller` attribute on the `<body>`  tag.
2. Scoping all the JS in a namespace.
3. A JS Util then matches and loads the JS in the JS namespace for the `data-controller`  by convention.

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

```
JsSpace.on('users', {
  index: function(){
    console.log('index action of users controller');
  }
});
```

that pattern implemented by render controller and action into body attribute then
fetch them and execute the match function. 
[js-namespace-rails](https://github.com/falm/js-namespace-rails)